# Why can vectorization reduce the use of virtual functions?

Tags: optimization, query

**Vectorized Query** can be very helpful to get a high-performance analytical systems.

I know that **vectorization** can execute all operations on blocks of values (SIMD instructions) instead of interpreting a query expression tuple at a time.
But how can I understand ,the vectorization can reduce the overhead of virtual functions?

---

This question came to me when I read **a paper from TU Munich**:
[Data Blocks: Hybrid OLTP and OLAP on Compressed Storage using both Vectorization and Compilation](http://db.in.tum.de/downloads/publications/datablocks.pdf)

> The jump in query evaluation efficiency is typically achieved by using vectorized execution where, instead of interpreting query expressions tuple at a time, all
>   operations are executed on blocks of values. The effect is reduced interpretation overhead because virtual functions implementing block-wise operations handle thousands of tuples per function call, and the loop over the block inside these function implementations benefits from many loop-driven compiler optimizations including the automatic generation
>   of SIMD instructions.

Such formulation could also be found in other DBMS papers, because vectorization is a popular way.

This question is related with general DBMS and the Paper from TUM is related with `HyPer`, which is a not so "famous" DBMS. I would be glad to receive any kinds of examples, explanations. If I have wrong with formulation, just feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glancing through the paper, it sounds like the answer is as simple as this:

- for "row-based" (non vectorized) operations, the (virtual) functions used to process query results have to be called once per row.
- for "batch-based" (vectorized) operations, the (virtual) functions are called once per batch, and then optimized loops can be run inside the virtual function implementation (reducing virtual function overhead by virtue of just calling those functions less times)

The is mostly covered in the quote you mentioned

> ...virtual functions implementing block-wise operations handle thousands of tuples per function call...

Calling a function once, to handle thousands of rows, is going to much cheaper than calling the function thousands of times, once for each row.

In any program, there is overhead to calling functions, especially virtual functions (looking up the actual function implementation's address in a lookup table, missing out on certain compile-time optimizations because the actual implementation function isn't known until runtime, etc - see [In C++ why and how are virtual functions slower?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191637/in-c-why-and-how-are-virtual-functions-slower/191647) for more discussion on virtual function overhead).

Looking to SQL Server's implementation of batch-based query processing (I realize the paper is about HyPer, but the general principles hold), you can find other sources discussing the per-row vs per-batch cost savings in terms of CPU.  Consider this post:

[Columnstore Index Performance: BatchMode Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/columnstore-index-performance-batchmode-execution/)

It compares row based processing:

> 1. Query was executed in ROW mode. The predicate was applied to 3580 rows, one row at a time, to get 1200 qualified rows
> 2. ...The actual CPU cost was 15 ms...

To batch based processing:

> 1. The query (specifically SCAN operator) was executed in BatchMode. There were two batches, each containing 900 rows, were executed. The predicate was applied to 900 rows at one time
> 2. ...the actual execution time is < 1 ms (the minimal time that can be measured)...

Processing query results in batches thus reduces CPU costs in SQL Server for a number of reasons, but virtual function call overhead is likely one of them (although it's probably less significant than, say, operating on compressed data, applying predicates per batch, calculating aggregates per batch, etc).